# Delete ubuntu partition (dual boot windows 7)

Tags: windows-7

I deleted ubuntu partition from windows 7 hard disk partitions. But i fear when i restart my machine it will go into grub rescue. Any solution to avoid this.? Mix mbr /grub

Answer (score 0):

You should boot from windows 7 dvd then run:

```
# diskpart
# list volume
```

Determine your windows installation drive its always volume C: then go to your volume path

```
# cd /d C:
```

Run this :

```
# attrib +h +s C:\bootmgr    
# bootrec /fixboot    
# bootrec /fixmbr    
# bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

After this few steps you should make repair for your master boot record